# Strip digits from list in Python, hour format

Tags: python, regex, datetime, strip

I get a list out looking like this: (hours)

list = ['02:00', '01:00', '03:00', '00:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '23:00', '24:00', '07:00', '22:00', '14:00', '13:00', '15:00', '21:00', '08:00', '16:00', '12:00', '20:00', '17:00', '11:00', '18:00', '09:00', '10:00']

in the end of my function it looks like this when I sort out the list:

```
list = nsmallest(HoursPerDay, my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
    return [i.strip(':0') for i in list]
```

And it gives me this:
list = ['2', '1', '3', '', '4', '5', '6', '23', '24', '7', '22', '14', '13', '15', '21', '8', '16', '12', '2', '17', '11', '18', '9', '1']

Works fine on every hour except for 20:00 that it makes into 2 instead of 20 and make 00:00 into nothing.
How do I solve this? I have tried some regex generators too but I can´t get it right.

Comment: What do you actually want your output to look like. The empty string resulting from '00:00' seems unusual. Also, don't use *list* as a variable name

Comment: It is the default behaviour of `strip` if you specify more than 1 character then it will look for combinations of `:` and `0` from both left and right and if found it will strip that off. Thatswhy in `00:00` it searches 0 from either side and strips off and `:` as well so leaving the empty string. Same goes for `20:00` because it first strip  0 from right and then : from right.

Comment: Do you really want your final output to be a list of strings containing integers, rather than integers or some objects specifically suited for times?? What exactly are you going to use this output for?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than stripping you should be splitting. Something like this:

```
inlist = ['02:00', '01:00', '03:00', '00:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '23:00', '24:00', '07:00', '22:00', '14:00', '13:00', '15:00', '21:00', '08:00', '16:00', '12:00', '20:00', '17:00', '11:00', '18:00', '09:00', '10:00']

outlist = [f"{int(e.split(':')[0])}" for e in inlist]

print(outlist)
```

**Output:**

```
['2', '1', '3', '0', '4', '5', '6', '23', '24', '7', '22', '14', '13', '15', '21', '8', '16', '12', '20', '17', '11', '18', '9', '10']
```

**Note:**

The conversion to int and back to string effectively removes any leading zero

Answer (score 0):

If we use the following snippet, your desired result can be achieved.

`[(i.removesuffix(':00')).lstrip('0') or '0' for i in list]`

1. Removing the :00 suffix.
2. Removing leading zero. [ `lstrip` ]
3. Special case for "00:00".

Another alternate solution using the regex:

`[str(int(re.sub("\:00$", "", i))) for i in list]`

1. Removing the :00 suffix. [ `re.sub("\:00$", "", i` ]
2. Removing leading zero by converting to int.
3. Converting every element to string as required.

Comment: That won't work. For example with '02:00' this will produce '02' whereas '2' is what's required

Comment: @OldBill then for `00:00` OP wants `0` or `00` ?

Comment: @OldBill, thank you for pointing out. What do you think of the revised snippet ?

Comment: @kgkmeekg Look what happens to '00:00'

Comment: Yep '00:00' was changing to 0 (integer) instead of '00'. It is unclear if '00:00' should be '0' or '00', so I a going to consider both correct as long as it is a string. Added another simpler solution using regex.

Answer (score 0):

`strip` default behaviour as given in python documentation is

***Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped.***

```
'00010:010:000'.strip(':0')  # it will remove all available combination of ':0' 
# you will get '10:01'
```

Now for your specific requirement

```
[i.rstrip('0').rstrip(':') for i in list]
```

If you want to retain zeroes from right side after first 0 removed then use

```
import re
list = ['02:00', '01:00', '03:00', '00:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '23:00', '24:00', '07:00', '22:00', '14:00', '13:00', '15:00', '21:00', '08:00', '16:00', '12:00', '20:00', '17:00', '11:00', '18:00', '09:00', '10:00']
[re.sub(r'0+(.+)', r'\1', i.rstrip('0').rstrip(':')) for i in list]
# ['2', '1', '3', '0', '4', '5', '6', '23', '24', '7', '22', '14', '13', '15', '21', '8', '16', '12', '20', '17', '11', '18', '9', '10']
```